# How could "printf (cout)" change uninitialized local variable?

Tags: c++

I made a mistake and used uninitialized local variable in a function and happened to find a single line of "cout" could change the uninitialized value. To simplify, I show the problem as follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void){
  int i;
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i = 777;
}
int main(void){
  foo();
  //cout << "hello!" << endl;
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

The line I comment out will change the output from (unknown#;777) to (unknown#;hello!;0). Could someone help explain? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?

Comment: You are printing out an uninitialized variable? What value do you think it could be - anything perhaps?

Comment: Because `cout` is C++?

Comment: undefined behaviour cannot be defined - ie. looking at an uninitialised variable is looking at arbitrary memory - what is in that memory may depend on what code has executed previously but may or may not be repeatable depending on your environment

Comment: Look up "Undefined behavior".

Comment: @graham.reeds - But it is a comment!

Comment: `i` is (at least by most compilers) placed on the stack, and you read a value that happens to be there. Function calls (for example output to cout) use the stack too, so it just happens cout changes the stack in that way.

Comment: I get `777 777` and `777 hello 777` with Clang and -O3. It goes to show you that you can't even rely on the stack explanation.

Comment: @EdHeal he does say if he uncomments that line it changes the output of the program. He is learning. I probably made similar mistakes in 1995.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of stack behavior.

The first case:

```
int main(void){
  foo();
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

The first `foo()` builds the stack and initialize the location of `i` with `777` and leave it as is. Then, the second call to `foo()` lays on the same stack structure where location of `i` is still `777`. So, in this case `printf` prints `777`.

The second case:

`cout << "hello!" << endl` is actually calling two functions:

```
cout.operator<<("hello!");
cout.operator<<(endl);
```

Which overwrites our previously created stack structure.